# Can I only generate base classes when calling Doctrine::generateModelsFromYaml()?

Tags: model, yaml, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

I am using Doctrine::generateModelsFromYaml(). It creates a directory filled with base classes. Cool. I'm guessing the point of separating the base classes is to store only column definitions and relationships (in other words, only things that can be gleamed from the DB. The extension models, on the other hand, will be edited with behaviors, etc..

So how do I only update the base classes and not the extended classes when calling Doctrine::generateModelsFromYaml again?

EDIT: If my theory about the purpose of base classes ("I'm guessing the point of separating the base classes is to store only column definitions and relationships") is wrong, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that only the base classes are edited by default. Great!